# Memory space consumption

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list

Is there a situation where the extra memory space taken by the linked list pointers is more than the extra memory consumed by an array for the same problem if the problem can be solved with both the structures?

Answer (score 1):

A linked list is for dynamically sized data, with inserts and removes. Typically on the heap. Comparing this with an array would mean that this array uses a strategy from being oversized with unused entries for extra inserts, and sometimes being reallocated if the arrays threatens to overflow.

So it depends on the actual array strategy and the behavior of the program, knowledge of it.

However for every entry the actual data needs space too, maybe a pointer and an allocated object.
Look at the linked-list overhead like a form of indexing, like in a database.
So memory is more or less irrelevant.

One should only be aware, that for instance a linked list of booleans is not really clever.